# Grouping a List of objects by property, split into multiple lists.

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, struct

**Current Structure** (Cannot change due to requirements of the system)

```
class Statement
{
    string section;
    string category;
    string statement;
}
```

**Example Statement list**

```
section      category     statement
1            a            apple
1            a            banana
1            b            potato
2            c            car
2            c            bus
2            d            plane
```

**Problem**

I start with a `List<Statement>`, and need to split them up based on Section, and then category into the following (or similar) structure

```
struct SectionCollection
{
    string sectionName {get{return categories[0].section;}}
    List<CategoryCollection> categories;
}

struct CategoryCollection
{
    string categoryName {get{return statements[0].category;}}
    List<Statement> statements;
}
```

So, from the `List<Statement>`, I should have a 
`List<SectionCollection>`, which inside has a 
`List<CategoryCollection>`, which inside has a 
`List<Statement>`

So in the above data example, I would have

- `List<SectionCollection>`

  - `List<CategoryCollection>` (Inside)

    - `List<Statement>` (Inside)

**Notes**

It's not impossible that A statement or a category might be the same in a different section - these still need to belong in different `SectionCollection`s

**Attempt**

My current attempt, which works until a null exception is eventually thrown on the inner for loop. This is one of those problems I've been staring at for a while now, so I know how confused this 'solution' may seem.

```
var sections = statements.GroupBy(x => x.section).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();
foreach(var section in sections)
{
     SectionCollection thisSection = new SectionCollection();
     var categories = section.GroupBy(x => x.category).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();

    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        thisSection.categories.Add(new CategoryCollection({statements = category});
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see where `thisSection.categories` is initialized with `new`

Comment: @MFisherKDX that may just be the problem.. I'm looking in to that now, but I feel like I've already tried this, and just (foolishly) left it out of the example I've provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting a null reference error is because you're not initializing the `Categories` list in `SectionCollection`.

Changing:

```
SectionCollection thisSection = new SectionCollection();
```

To:

```
SectionCollection thisSection = new SectionCollection() 
{ 
    Categories = new List<CategoryCollection>() 
};
```

Will fix the error. You're also not capturing the result anywhere, if you update your code to the below it should work:

```
var sections = statements.GroupBy(x => x.Section).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();

var result = new List<SectionCollection>();

foreach (var section in sections)
{
    SectionCollection thisSection = new SectionCollection() { Categories = new List<CategoryCollection>() };

    var categories = section.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();

    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        thisSection.Categories.Add(new CategoryCollection { Statements = category });
    }

    result.Add(thisSection);
}
```

But it might be a bit cleaner to give classes proper constructors and properties and move some of the logic there:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var statements = new List<Statement>()
        {
            new Statement(1, "a", "apple"),
            new Statement(1, "a", "banana"),
            new Statement(1, "b", "potato"),
            new Statement(2, "c", "car"),
            new Statement(2, "c", "bus"),
            new Statement(2, "d", "plane")
        };

        var sectionCollections = statements
            .GroupBy(s => s.Section)
            .Select(group => new SectionCollection(group.Key, statements))
            .ToList();
    }

    public class Statement
    {
        public Statement(int section, string category, string statementName)
        {
            Section = section;
            Category = category;
            StatementName = statementName;
        }

        public int Section { get; }

        public string Category { get; }

        public string StatementName { get; }
    }

    public class SectionCollection
    {
        public SectionCollection(int sectionName, List<Statement> statements)
        {
            SectionName = sectionName;

            Categories = statements
                .Where(s => s.Section == sectionName)
                .GroupBy(s => s.Category)
                .Select(group => new CategoryCollection(group.Key, group.ToList()))
                .ToList();
        }

        public int SectionName { get; }

        public List<CategoryCollection> Categories { get; }
    }

    public class CategoryCollection
    {
        public CategoryCollection(string categoryName, List<Statement> statements)
        {
            CategoryName = categoryName;
            Statements = statements;
        }

        public string CategoryName { get; }

        public List<Statement> Statements { get; }
    }
}
```

You'll end up with following structure:

[image: output structure]

Comment: Thanks very much @RagtimeWilly,

As I said in one of my previous comments/reponses, I *had* tried it with initializing the constructors, but was still facing null references at some point. 

Ultimately, the way you have set up your LINQ expressions in your example has pointed me towards the solution!  I learn something new every time with Linq, I swear!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `SectionCollection` object with:

```
SectionCollection thisSection = new SectionCollection();
```

But you never initialize the value `thisSection.categories` using `new` -- neither in the constructor or outside explicitly.

So when you attempt to access `thisSection.categories.Add` in your inner loop, you generate an exception.

Comment: I'm looking in to this further, but I'm not sure this is the issue.
(I've initialized all the lists, and am still facing null references with my attempt provided above)

Comment: ok @Bejasc, go ahead and edit your post and I'll delete my answer